# How do you remove widgets from GtkHBox?

Tags: gtk, gnome

Is there some kind of `unpack` function I can call to remove widgets from a GtkHBox ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`gtk_container_remove()`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkContainer.html#gtk-container-remove) is what you're looking for, or simply `gtk_widget_destroy()` if you're not going to use the widget for anything else.

Comment: if I call destroy on a widget such as an IconView, will all of that widgets children get destroyed as well ?

Comment: @Mad Rapper X, only if their reference count drops to zero.